# OrientDB - Java create a field as EMBEDDEDLIST type

Tags: java, orientdb, orientdb-2.1, embeddedlist

I try to create a field as type EMBEDDEDLIST from Java.

But when I try to create it, is considered as LINK.

If I define a field by Studio as EMBEDDELIST with linked class, Java works properly.

My code:

```
String fieldName = "trialEmbedded";
List<ODocument> fieldDataItem = doc.getData().field(fieldName);

DataItem di = DataItemFactory.create(dtValidita, importo, descrizione, db);

if (fieldDataItem == null) {
    fieldDataItem = new ArrayList<ODocument>();
}
fieldDataItem.add(di.getData());
doc.setField(fieldName, fieldDataItem);
```

In the doc variable (type ODocument) when I save it, on DB (querying by Studio) I've got in column "trialEmbedded" a link (orange box with @rid clickable), if I specify field as EMBEDDEDLIST works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved in very simple way.

I used the signature of setField with OType parameter, like this:

```
this.data.field(fieldName, fieldDataItem, OType.EMBEDDEDLIST);
```